# How to decode a codable property in two data types simply if one of them always is empty?

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decode, decodable

I receive from a post request, this JSON:

```
"clinic_info": {
                "city": "Querétaro",
                "state": "Querétaro",
                "country": "México",
                "phone": null,
                "ext": null,
                "coords": "20.6046089,-100.37826050000001",
                "location": "Querétaro"
            }
```

But when it is empty the JSON is:

```
"clinic_info": []
```

This produces an error: Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because `decoder` want `dictionary` and your `JSON` is `array`

Need to check before `decoding` that `JSON` response is `dictionary` or `Array` and do `decoding` accordingly.

If you find `Dictionary` then do like this

```
let myData = try JSONDecoder().decode(YourModel.self, from: jsonData)
```

If you find `Array` then do like this

```
let myData = try JSONDecoder().decode([YourModel].self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: @Christian4423: Thanks, Updated

Answer (score 0):

The `Array` class has a method for this.

Using `typeof` will always return `"object"`.

The code below shows how to use the `isArray()` method in the `Array` class.

```
const obj = {
  _array: [],
  _object: {}
}

console.log(Array.isArray(obj._array)); // true
console.log(Array.isArray(obj._object)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `try, throw` like that

```
import Foundation

struct ClinicData: Codable {
    let clinicInfo: ClinicInfo?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case clinicInfo = "clinic_info"
    }
}

struct ClinicInfo: Codable {
    let city, state, country: String
    let coords, location: String
}

// MARK: Convenience initializers

extension ClinicData {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(ClinicData.self, from: data)
    }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }


    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}


**get clinicInfo** 

   if  let clinicData =  try? ClinicData.init(data: Data()), let clinicInfo = 
    clinicData.clinicInfo{

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The service that provides those JSON responses replies with:

```
"clinic_info": { ... }
```

Where `...` is a valid JSON object.

But when it is empty, you are saying it looks like this:

```
"clinic_info": []
```

Notice the `[]` that say this is an empty **array of objects**.

You might want to change the service response (if possible), since it looks inconsistent to me having it return an object when it has valid data, and an array when there is no valid data.

The error message you are getting is clear:

> Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.

It expected an object `{}`, but found an array `[]`.